# Nutch Solr Auto Language Detection - Language-specific fields not appearing

Tags: solr, nutch

I am trying to enable language detection in Solr but the new language-specific fields are not appearing after indexing.

Here is my configuration thus far:

**solrconfig.xml:**

```
<processor class="org.apache.solr.update.processor.LangDetectLanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessorFactory">
                <str name="langid.fl">title</str>
                <str name="langid.langField">lang_detect</str>
                <str name="langid.fallback">en</str>
                <bool name="langid.map">true</bool>
                <str name="langid.map.lcmap">en:en, zh:zh</str>
                <bool name="langid.individual">true</bool>
                <str name="langid.individual.fl">title</str>
</processor>
<processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
<processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
```

**managed-schema.xml:**

```
<field name="lang123" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="title_en" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="title_zh" type="text_cjk" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

**Nutch_HOME/conf/nutch-site.xml:**

```
<property>
  <name>plugin.includes</name>
  <value>protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika)|index-(basic|anchor)|indexer-solr|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)|language-identifier</value>
</property>
```

After running full re-crawl and indexing to Solr, this is my sample output for a document:

```
{
           "tstamp":["2017-07-18T08:44:35.470Z"],
            "segment":[20170718164424],
            "digest":["23c66ec3785ca1fe1e71bc636e6f6f37"],
            "host":["test.com"],
            "boost":[1.0],
            "id":"https://test.com",
            "title":["保新"],
            "lang_detect":["zh"],
            "metatag.keywords":["meta keywords here",
              "meta keywords here"],
            "url":["http://test.com"],
            "content":["test test"],
            "_version_":12312312
    }
```

**Questions**

1. Why does 'lang' field appear, even though I had intentionally set the language detection field to be 'lang_detect'?
2. Neither 'title_zh', 'title_en' appears in the results. Is a step / configuration missed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I noticed is that you're trying to detect that language of the content in two places Solr and Nutch, usually you use one or the other. If you use the `language-identifier` plugin on Nutch the identification process hapens on Nutch alone, and basically on the Solr side you'll get one document with the language, so you don't need to use the `LangDetectLanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessorFactory` processor.

You could use the Solr processor if you want the language to be identified in the Solr side, so then you won't need the `language-identifier` plugin on Nutch, just pick one of the two.

As for the field question, the `language-identifier` plugin doesn't have an option to change the name of the field (https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/plugin/language-identifier/src/java/org/apache/nutch/analysis/lang/LanguageIndexingFilter.java#L76) so if you use it you'll get a `lang` field in your index.

For the second question, what would you expect to have on the `title_en`? The language identification on both Nutch/Solr just **detects** the language of the text and places this "classification" in a field (`lang_detect` in this case).

Comment: I see. So which part is it that enables the 'title' to be auto-detected by language and also copied to their respective 'title_en' , 'title_zh' fields?

Comment: Since we can see the `lang_detect` field in the Solr output the language detection on Solr is working, try removing the `langid.individual.*` options and index manually a document using the Solr Admin UI to test, right now not sure what would happen with the individual settings since you're setting there the same field as in `langid.fl`. I think (honestly don't remember at this point) this was the configuration that I've used in the past https://gist.github.com/jorgelbg/fe7944e8ca952074d293cd250100c1db, give it a try